# Как выполнять функцию после снятия захвата

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой фильтр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код к нему
html

```
<li class="catalog-filter-price">
              <p>Фильтр по цене</p>
              <p>
                <input id="min-cost" value="<?php echo $p_low; ?>" name="p_low" type="text" value="0" onchange="filter();" readonly>
                <input id="max-cost" value="<?php echo $p_high; ?>" name="p_high" type="text" value="100000" onchange="filter();" readonly>
                <span>Р</span>
              </p>
              <input type="text" id="price-filter">
            </li>
```

js

```
     $('.product-slider-big').slick({
      asNavFor: '.product-slider-small',
      fade: true,
      arrows: false
    });
    $('.product-slider-small').slick({
      asNavFor: '.product-slider-big',
      focusOnSelect: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
    //ion range slider
    var $range = $("#price-filter"),
        $from = $("#min-cost"),
        $to = $("#max-cost"),
        range,
        min = 0,
        max = 100000,
        from,
        to;
    var updateValues = function () {
        $from.prop("value", from);
        $to.prop("value", to);
    };
    $range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        min: min,
        max: max,
        hide_min_max: true,
        force_edges: true,
        prettify_enabled: false,
        onChange: function (data) {
            from = data.from;
            to = data.to;
            updateValues();
        }
    });
    range = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");
    var updateRange = function () {
        range.update({
            from: from,
            to: to
        });
    };
    $from.on("change", function () {
        from = +$(this).prop("value");
        if (from < min) {
            from = min;
        }
        if (from > to) {
            from = to;
        }
        updateValues();    
        updateRange();
    });
    $to.on("change", function () {
        to = +$(this).prop("value");
        if (to > max) {
            to = max;
        }
        if (to < from) {
            to = from;
        }
        updateValues();    
        updateRange();
    });

    //кнопка сброса фильтра
    var slider = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");
    var check = $('#js-filter').find('input[type="checked"]');
    $('#js-reset').click(function () {
      $($from).val(0);
      $($to).val(100000);
      slider.reset();
      $(check).attr('checked', false);
    });
    //fancy select
    $('#sort-list').fancySelect();




  });
```

Вопрос в том как мне сделать так, чтобы только после того как завершится перемещение элемента выполнилась функция `Upd();`

Comment: А обработчик [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover)  не подойдет? Вот [пример](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/LWGagW)

Answer (score 1):

Что то тупанул...

```
onFinish: function (data) {
                alert("onFinish");
            }
```

Целиком

```
 $range.ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            min: min,
            max: max,
            hide_min_max: true,
            force_edges: true,
            prettify_enabled: false,
            onChange: function (data) {
                from = data.from;
                to = data.to;
                updateValues();
            },
            onFinish: function (data) {
                alert("onFinish");
            }
        });
```